# Magento 2 checkout form customer email value pre-fill does not work while other works

Tags: magento2, guest-checkout, default-values

I am using Magento 2.3. I am trying to pre-fill fields in Magento checkout form.
 I have done following. I followed [this](https://webkul.com/blog/autofill-custom-address-magento2/) article.

First I defined dependency injection at `vendor/module/etc/frontend/di.xml`.
I believe it is working.

After that, I created **layoutprocessor** at **`Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php`** with following contents:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor 
{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = 'First Name';
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['customer-email']['value'] = 'default@example.com';
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['value'] = 'Street Line one';

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

My problem is that, the `firstname` field gets filled with the value, while `customer-email` field does not get filled with the supplied value. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: change this your email line with this one `$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['customer-email']['value'] = 'default@example.com'`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of create plugin  on `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`

Create plugin on `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider` and use **after plugin method** on `getConfig` prefill  email id  But  avoid it on `loggedin customer` as it already has email.

**di.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_MagentoAnswer_Plugin_Magento_Checkout_Model_DefaultConfigProvider" sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\MagentoAnswer\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

***Plugin Class***

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\MagentoAnswer\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    /**
     * @var HttpContext
     */
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        HttpContext $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if (!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && is_array($result)) {
            $result['validatedEmailValue'] = 'john.deo@gmail.com';
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * Check if customer is logged in
     *
     * @return bool
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    private function isCustomerLoggedIn()
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

For all those who are looking to autofill email, i did it by adding a phtml file on checkout.

I had guest email in customer session and wants to prefill on checkout,
(you can also save that in session) i created a block which pass this email from session to phtml. (Please refer other docs to do this if you don't know)

*app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/ checkout_index_index.xml*

Add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\EmailFill" name="content.options" template="Company_Module::autofillemail.phtml" before="checkout.root" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

in *app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/autofillemail.phtml*

```
<?php

 //take guest email from block

 $email = $block->getGuestEmail(); //define this function in your block, code not in this answer DIY

 $guestEmail = isset($email) ? $email : '';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery","domReady!"], function ($) {
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            var email = "<?php echo $guestEmail; ?>";
            if (email !== "") {
                jQuery("#customer-email").val(email);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will Help Someone and save their time!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your email line of code to look similar with the firstname:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor 
{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = 'First Name';
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['customer-email']['value'] = 'default@example.com';
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['value'] = 'Street Line one';

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

> You are just missing the **`['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']`**